# Invalid Hook Call at material ui textfield component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Hello i'm building a personal project and it's delaying me with the following error:

```
react-refresh-runtime.development.js:315 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
   at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1484:1)
   at useTheme (useTheme.js:4:1)
   at useStyles (makeStyles.js:222:1)
   at WithStyles (withStyles.js:55:1)
   at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
   at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
   at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
   at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
   at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

I'm trying to use material-ui components inside a log in page and one day was working but now it giving me this error and i have no idea why or how to solve it. The page renders with a simple html input but i put a material-ui textfield it call the invalid hook call.

The code is the following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { loginUser } from "../redux/user";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user, status } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const login = async () => {
    let obj = { email, password };
    await dispatch(loginUser({ obj: obj }));
    await console.log(user);
    await console.log(status);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

the package.json is the following:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

I really appreciate if you could guide through this and thanks in advance.

Edit: Added code as requested.

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import Login from "./pages/Login";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={
              <main>
                <p>Oops, you went to wrong route. Please try another.</p>
              </main>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk("user/Login", async ({ obj }) => {
  return axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", {
      email: obj.email,
      password: obj.password,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    status: null,
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [loginUser.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [loginUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
      state.status = "success";
    },
    [loginUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "rejected";
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

npm ls react

```
+-- @emotion/react@11.10.4
| +-- @emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks@1.0.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @emotion/styled@11.10.4
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @mui/icons-material@5.10.3
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @mui/material@5.10.3
| +-- @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.95
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @mui/system@5.10.3
| | +-- @mui/private-theming@5.10.3
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | +-- @mui/styled-engine@5.10.3
| | | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- @mui/utils@5.10.3
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| +-- react-transition-group@4.4.5
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.5
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- @testing-library/react@13.3.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-dom@18.2.0
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-redux@8.0.2
| +-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
|   `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-router-dom@6.3.0
| +-- react-router@6.3.0
| | `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
+-- react-scripts@5.0.1
| `-- react@18.2.0 deduped
`-- react@18.2.0
```

Comment: You should use `await` with function calls that return a `Promise`. Not before `console.log`.

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by that? can you be more specific

Comment: I can't see the issue in your code. Please add the code that is using your `<Login/>` component. I've added your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-wave-xmt50n?file=/src/App.js) without your mentioned problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping.
Just added the things where <Login /> is being used

Comment: In the `login` function in the `Login` component, the 3 `await`s are unnecessary. (slightly unsure about the 1st one)

Answer (score -1):

Apparently i found the solution.
It was the material-ui components.
i was calling them like this `import { ButtonBase } from "@material-ui/core";` while they should be called like this:  `import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";`

I will fix the awaits as well in the component.
I thank you all for the help and cheers!